# PHP Core - where can I find the code coverage report in azure pipelines?

Tags: php, azure, code-coverage, open-source, php-code-coverage

Maybe I am burn out but:

1. Anyone knows how can I see the code coverage report in Azure Pipelines of the PHP Core project? I have this link:  https://dev.azure.com/phpazuredevops/PHP/_build?definitionId=1&_a=summary
2. How can I generate it locally in my computer?

Comment: Click into one of the runs and you’ll find it: https://dev.azure.com/phpazuredevops/PHP/_build/results?buildId=25553&view=codecoverage-tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Chris Hass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231316/chris-haas), your comment lead me to the right answer.

Basically are different jobs in the pipeline and **not all of them report the code coverage**.

In order to check the code coverage we need to look for the jobs with the "**Scheduled for**" tag ... like in the image:

[image]